# Django, Looping Through Zipped Lists Twice

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, iterator, django-views

So in essence the problem that I have is I cannot iterate through a zipped list twice. I've tried to copy the zipped list twice .

```
list = zip(vmarray, uuidarray)
```

This is where the list containing the vm's, in the view portion of the code is instantiated.

```
def malware(request):
     list, dictofvms = listofvms()
     listcopy = iter(list)
     list, listcopy = tee(listcopy)
     malwarelist = listofmalware()

return render(request, 'malware.html', {"malwarelist": malwarelist, "list": list, "listcopy": listcopy})
```

This is the part of the code that transmits the request through to the actual webpage.

Now when accessing it in the code when i loop through the malware list. It only allows me to loop through the list once, due to it being zipped/ an iterator. If there's any way that I can loop through the items that'd be fantastic. (there must be something simple) [i'm probably just being stupid]

```
  {% for malware in malwarelist %}
{{ malware }}

      {% for vm, uuid in list %}
          {{ vm }}
   {% endfor %}



          {% for vm, uuid in listcopy %}
      {{ vm }}
   {% endfor %}






  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can create a single list from the iterator and pass only that to your template context:

```
def malware(request):
    lst, dictofvms = listofvms()
    lst = list(lst)
    malwarelist = listofmalware()
    return render(request, 'malware.html', {"malwarelist": malwarelist, 
                                            "lst": lst})
```

Notice, how I've avoided using `list` as the name of the list to not shadow the built-in list function which is required to create a list from the iterator object.

Comment: Thanks Moses you're a star!

Answer (score 4):

The result of using `zip` is a `zip object` and not a list. Once you iterate through a `zip object` it is exhausted and you cannot iterate through it again.

A solution to this is to convert your zipped object to a list which can be iterated over multiple times like such:

`mylist = list(zip(vmarray, uuidarray))`

Comment: This is the simplest solution once you are in this situation